# EventLog for a service is throwing an error stating source is not set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, event-log

This is the first time I have set up a service for an application, I pretty much followed the step-by-step on the [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx). To create the eventLog1 as instructed by the website I went to design view and drag and dropped an event log into the service. From there I followed how to add the source and log, but when I run the app i keep getting "Source property was not set before writing to the event log." Is there a better way to create these? Outside of the eventlog the service runs correctly.

```
 public FGLFileTransferService()
    {
        eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("FGLTransferServiceSource"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("FGLTransferServiceSource", "FGLTransferServiceLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "FGLTransferServiceSource";
        eventLog1.Log = "FGLTransferServiceLog";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Start");
        Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        //timer.Interval = 1; 
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;  //new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();

    }
```

Stack trace

```
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message)
   at FGLFileTransfers.FGLFileTransferService.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Users\brandon_paxton\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FGLFileTransfers1.2\FGLFileTransfers\FGLFileTransferService.cs:line 42
   at FGLFileTransfers.FGLFileTransferService.OnDebug() in C:\Users\brandon_paxton\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FGLFileTransfers1.2\FGLFileTransfers\FGLFileTransferService.cs:line 37
   at FGLFileTransfers.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\brandon_paxton\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FGLFileTransfers1.2\FGLFileTransfers\Program.cs:line 26
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I suspect you should call the InitializeComponent() as first in the constructor and only then set your values. You should try that.

Comment: Christ.. Thanks. I was staring at that far too long thinking I did something wrong setting up the eventlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor `FGLFileTransferService()` first call the `InitializeComponent()` and only after you can set your own values. Otherwise they will get overwritten.

The solution will look like this:

```
public FGLFileTransferService()
    {
        // *** replaced this
        InitializeComponent();
        // *** replaced this
        eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("FGLTransferServiceSource"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("FGLTransferServiceSource", "FGLTransferServiceLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "FGLTransferServiceSource";
        eventLog1.Log = "FGLTransferServiceLog";
            }
```